# How to get rid of the console window

Tags: c++, windows, console, mingw

I have tried to make a simple `MessageBox` using this code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  MessageBox(NULL, "Hello", "Message Box", MB_OKCANCEL);
}
```

But upon building this in the Dev-C++ IDE with the MinGW toolchain, I get a console window popping up behind the `MessageBox`.

Is there a way to get rid of this console window?

Comment: You should probably use a more up-to-date IDE.  [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is probably the modern equivalent of Dev-C++.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, compile for the "windows" subsystem.  Here are [instructions for performing this task on multiple IDEs](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.DisablingConsoleWindow).

Comment: -1: Excellent, an answer about Visual Studio on a question about MinGW GCC.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: this has nothing to do with Visual Studio, it's part of the Windows Executable format.

Comment: A switch to the Visual Studio compiler has everything to do with Visual Studio. Your edit is much better.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I used the term "subsystem" as it is part of Microsoft's terminology.  Someone else edited my post and included a link the visual studio switch.  I added the instructions for several IDEs while removing that link.

Comment: That's excellent! I see now that that was @jeffamaphone getting carried away. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Dev-C++; use a decent IDE instead.
2. Compile for the WINDOWS subsystem, instead of the CONSOLE one. Even braindead Dev-C++ should have option for that (the entry point should be called `WinMain` — see any introduction to Windows programming).

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
HWND hwnd;
AllocConsole();
hwnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
MessageBox(NULL, "Hello", "Message Box", MB_OKCANCEL);
ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).